# For each three items in an array, concatenate a string from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to achieve a list of all subjects from an array that has been concatenated to a string from another array using Javascript.
For example:

```
var Alevels = ["Accounting", "Arts, Crafts and Design", "Biology", 
    "Chemistry", "Classical Civilisation", "Computer Science", "Dance"];

var Degrees = ["Animal Conservation", "Business", "Business and Management",
    "Business and Computing","Business with Events Management","Computing",
    "Digital Technology","Early Childhood Studies","electronics and Communications"];
```

What i want the Javascript to do is to pick three values from the Alevels array and then to choose one from the Degrees array and concatenate the values together **without showing the same string in a different order** like this:

```
var string = AlevelValue1 + " - " + AlevelValue2 + " - " + AlevelValue3 + " 
    = " + degreeValue;
```

Currently i have the following code but this only takes one value from the Alevels list and one value from the Degrees list:

```
for (let value1 of Alevels) {
    for (let value2 of Degrees) {
        var div = document.createElement('li');
        div.innerHTML = value1 + " - " + value2;
        Table.appendChild(div);
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly apprecieated!

Many thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "choose" one from the degree list? Are you looking for all the combinations of 3-alevels and 1-degree values?

Comment: Yes exactly. Sorry for being unclear that is exactly right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way would be to calculate all the combinations of 3 Alevels, then concat all the Degrees on to these combinations.

```js
var Alevels = ["Accounting", "Arts, Crafts and Design", "Biology", 
    "Chemistry", "Classical Civilisation", "Computer Science", "Dance"];

var Degrees = ["Animal Conservation", "Business", "Business and Management",
    "Business and Computing","Business with Events Management","Computing",
    "Digital Technology","Early Childhood Studies","electronics and Communications"];
    
function getCombinations(array, length) {
    function fork(i, t) {
        if (t.length === length) {
            result.push(t);
            return;
        }
        if (i === array.length) {
            return;
        }
        fork(i + 1, t.concat([array[i]]));
        fork(i + 1, t);
    }

    var result = [];
    fork(0, []);
    return result;
}

var aLevelCombinations = getCombinations(Alevels, 3);
var finalCombinations = [];

for (var i = 0; i < Degrees.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < aLevelCombinations.length; j++) {
      var newList = [].concat(aLevelCombinations[j]).join(' - ');
      newList = newList + ' = ' + Degrees[i];
      finalCombinations.push(newList);
    }
}

console.log(finalCombinations);
```

Comment: Disclaimer: I got the function to generate combinations from a SO answer which I can't find right now. I had copied the function to my collection of beautiful code. I'm searching for the original answer and will link it here.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Like so? Always three items of `Alevels`, plus one from `Degrees`. I assume the given order is right.

```
var result = [],
    inputA = [].concat(Alevels),
    inputB = [].concat(Degrees);

while (inputA.length > 0) {

  result.push(
    //first three items (removed) of Array A
    inputA.splice(0,3)
     //combine with
     .concat(
       //first item (removed) of Array B
       [inputB.shift()]
       //join together
     ).join(' '));
}
```